# Branching Brownian Motion and KPP equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, heat-equation

I have troubles understanding the proof of the connection between BBM and KPP equation. I mean the proof of the next lemma from the lecture notes of Anton Bovier about BBM, [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qhxvkrbljb9qw0/pragueschool.pdf). This is almost whole proof, on the next page only the formula (3.10) is repeated.

[image]

My problem is, I do not see how to get equation (3.10) from (3.11). I did some computations, to no avail. I have checked the original work of McKean ([44]), but there explanation is even more concise.

Comment: Someone has deleted their comment with a hint. The answer to my question is essentially contained in (1) and (2) here:  J.M. Ball. Strongly continuous semigroups, weak solutions, and the variation of constants formula, http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-063-02/S0002-9939-1977-0442748-6/S0002-9939-1977-0442748-6.pdf